# multi thread data loss issue, main loop sometimes gets empty data when the data is not empty

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, thread-safety, semaphore

I`m writing library that share data between threads,

```
bool Broker::publish(const std::string& topic, void* data, size_t len)
{
    int queue_pos = getQueueHead();
    if (queue_pos == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "WARNING: broker buffer is full\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> parsed_topic = parseTopic(topic);

    void* data_ptr = malloc(len);
    memcpy(data_ptr, data, len);
    std::shared_ptr<void> data_share(data_ptr, free);

    _buffer[queue_pos] = Buffer{parsed_topic, data_share, len}; // <- put data (_buffer is simple array)
    sem_post(&_work[queue_pos]); // <- allow the run to continue
    return true;
}

void Broker::run()
{
    while (_should_run)
    {
        // sleep if buffer empty
        if (queueSize() == 0)
        {
            sem_wait(&_work[_queue_tail]); // <- wait
            continue;
        }

        // pull from buffer
        const auto [topic, data, len] = std::move(_buffer[_queue_tail]); // <- pull

        // release queue space
        _queue_tail = (_queue_tail + 1) % BROKER_QUEUE_SIZE;

// more code...
}
```

the problem that I`m facing is that even that the main loop waiting for the semaphore, some times, it pass the semaphore - which means that the publisher placed data in the array but the main loop reads empty structure, and if I print the value sleep for 10 us then read again - the first time is empty and the second time have data.

I tried to put `asm("" ::: "memory");` before the sem_post but it did not help,
tried _mm_mfence, to check if it cache problem, but still the same,
I passed on the ASM of the program using gdb but it look like it first putting the data in the array and then calling the semaphore.

Comment: There are no memory barriers or synchronisation points in the above code. Note that `sem_post` and `sem_wait` are not synchronisation points only thread safe to call.

Comment: But at the point of reading in the loop the data should be in the array, that means that the data is not placed in the array before the `sem_post`?

Comment: No it means that you have a data-race with threads reading and writing the same location with no synchronisation - "_...If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined...."_ from [Threads and data races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races)

Comment: How many independent publisher threads and consumer threads are there?

Comment: Consumer is only one- the main loop, publishers can be more then 20 or even higher

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the thread synchronization code with the processing logic which is going to make it much harder to debug and maintain.

You could use a well-known (can't quite say standard since it is missing from the `C++` standard library) data structure like a multi-publisher, multi-consumer queue to handle the communication. You are then free to focus on the logic. There are several robust implementations on GitHub.

Or, here is some sample code that might do the job.

### Multi-Producer, Multi-Consumer Queue

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

template<typename T>
class MpMc
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    void push(const T& element)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.push_back(element);
        lock.unlock();
        m_condition_variable.notify_one();
    }

    void push_sentinel()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_sentinel = m_queue.size();
        m_condition_variable.notify_all();
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_queue.empty();
    }

    bool pop_nowait(T& element)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (m_queue.empty() or m_sentinel == 0)
            return false;

        --m_sentinel;
        element = m_queue.front();
        m_queue.pop_front();
        return true;
    }

    bool pop(T& element)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (m_sentinel == 0)
            return false;

        while (m_queue.empty())
        {
            m_condition_variable.wait(lock);
            if (m_sentinel == 0)
                return false;
        }

        --m_sentinel;
        element = m_queue.front();
        m_queue.pop_front();
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> m_queue;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_condition_variable;
    int m_sentinel = -1;
};
```

Comment: queue is not what i need, in my implementation every publisher get position in the array and just put the data there, post the semaphore and continue, not need to wait to the other threads in order to fill the queue. also this not answer me why the main loop wont see the data when it need to be there..

Comment: I think the queue will do exactly what you need -- allow the publishers to `push` data onto the queue and continue on independently of the other publishers. Of course, `push` will serialize access to the queue as there has to be some type of synchronization between threads, but that should be a minimal cost given you are parsing and doing memory allocations for each element. If you actually need higher performance, you can consider a lock free ring, but I am skeptical you are at that point.